# "frozen" minecraft items

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How do you summon an item that's "frozen" in space and that cannot be picked up in minecraft? I just can't seem to do it. I tried the "NoAI" tag and it still spawned, but as a regular item.

Answer (score 1):

You can have an unpickupable (that's not a word) item by using the `PickupDelay` tag.

```
/summon ~ ~ ~ Item {Item:{id:#,Damage:#,Count:#,tag:{###}}, PickupDelay: #}

Replace the '#' with the correct values.
```

To make it immobile (static in space), you don't use the `NoAI` tag as it does not have any AI (unlike mobs/creatures). All it does is make it immobile (until you break the block under it to make it fall or push it). Instead, you can:

- Use the `NoGravity` tag. (Though it'll still have its bobbing effect)
- Attach it to an invisible armor stand and reorient the hands to be facing straight ahead (parallel to the ground).

Comment: 1.13 syntax: `/summon item ~ ~ ~ {Item:{id:###,Count:#,tag:{###}},PickupDelay:#}`

Answer (score 0):

In general, standard item entities cannot be "frozen" in place. Maybe in a future update. However, there is a workaround.

Armor stands can hold items, which have properties similar to that of a "frozen" item. Just make sure to make the armor stand invisible, invulnerable, and unable to have items removed from it!

Comment: +1 for suggesting armour stands, which can be used for items such as weapons, armour and tools. Although your first statement is incorrect, as you can see from the other answer

Answer (score -2):

Version: **1.11.2**

You can apply the `NoGravity` tag on the item and set the `PickupDelay` tag to a very high value. It used to be that you can set the `Count` tag of an item to make it indefinitely unable to be picked up, but that was in an older version.

Your command would look something like this: (where `stone` is whatever block you want)

```
/summon item ~ ~ ~ {Item:{id:stone,Count:1},NoGravity:1,PickupDelay:999999999,NoAI:0}
```

As far as freezing an item goes, you can stop the item from moving and changing its position, but you can't freeze the animation without putting it on an armorstand (which would alter the size).

Comment: This doesn't add anything new that the other answers haven't already covered